# Gamma distribution and Cramér-Rao bound

Tags: maximum-likelihood, gamma-distribution, fisher-information

There are two definitions of the [GAMMA distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Maximum_likelihood_estimation):

I did the ML estimation, generated the Fisher Information, compared it to the Variance and the Cramer Lower Bound was reached, so the estimator is efficient. But now I tried it with this alternative:

$$g(x;\alpha,\beta) = x^{\alpha-1}\frac{\beta^{\alpha}e^{-\beta x}}{\Gamma (\alpha)}$$

I did the ML estimation and got an estimator for the $\beta$:

$$\beta_{ML}=\frac{N\alpha}{\sum x_i}$$

which is correct, as I looked up in this book: [Yudi Pawitan In All Likelihood:
Statistical Modelling and Inference Using Likelihood](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198507658) (pp. 60-61). The Fisher Information Matrix entry for $\beta$ is $=\frac{N\alpha}{\beta^2}$. Now I wanted to see if the Cramer Rao Bound is reached, so:

$$V(\beta_{ML})=V(\frac{N\alpha}{\sum x_i})=N^2\alpha^2*\frac{1}{\sum V(x_i)}$$

with $V(x_i)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta^2}$. I get the following if I insert it:

$$=\frac{N^2\alpha^2}{\alpha / \beta^2}=\frac{N^2\alpha}{\beta^2}=V(\beta_{ML})$$

Cramer-Rao-Bound:
$$V(\beta_{ML})=I^{-1}(\beta_{ML})$$

this gives:
$$\frac{N^2\alpha}{\beta^2}=(\frac{N\alpha}{\beta^2})^{-1}$$
which is not true, because:
$$\frac{N^2\alpha}{\beta^2}>\frac{\beta^2}{N\alpha}$$

So in this case,the CR lower bound is not reached, but as I said above, with the other definition of the Gamma distribution it worked. So, I made a mistake, but I can't see it.

Comment: We're happy to help, but is this homework, or what is the status exactly? We don't usually give explicit answers for questions people have about their homework, but rather give hints so that they are able to figure it out for themselves.

Comment: well no, this is not a homework. we have an exam about ml estimation and I thougth about which distribution they could come up with, we did not have gamma in our excercises, so thats why I think they will take it in the exam.... so I did it on my own, I just did a mistake and I can't find it? If you see it, it would be great if you show it to me, thanks.

Comment: Hints:  1) Look at the line of math after "if the Cramer Rao bound is reached, so:".  What happened to that $\Sigma$ when you moved to the next line?  2) Look carefully at that next line.  Are those expressions really equal?

Comment: ok, thanks a lot, I forgot an "N" and I did a mistake with the frac, but it is still not correct, because I get as the variance:
$N \alpha \beta^2$ and this is not equal to $\beta^2 /(N \alpha)$
Mh

Comment: You are plugging the variance into your expression for $V(\beta_{ML})$, but is it really true that the variance of $1/\Sigma x_i = 1/(N \sigma^2_x)$?  Somewhere around this site are questions about the delta-method, which can help you make this conversion, but the short form is you wind up multiplying by $\beta^{-4}$ (= $(\text{d}(1/\beta)/\text{d}\beta)^2)$.

Comment: mh, thanks a lot for helping me, but I can't move on, because I don't know how to calculate it: What is the Variance of $1/\sum x_i$? Mh, I don't get it, it has to be $(N\alpha/\beta^2)^{-1}$, but I don't see how I can get this? I don't understand how I should multiply this with $\beta^{-4}$?
An answer would be very appreciated.

Comment: First, do you know the distribution of $S = \sum_i X_i$. If so, can you find $\mathbb E(1/S)$ (*not* $1/\mathbb E S)$? How about $\mathbb E(1/S^2)$? [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/28836/7003) on math.SE may also be of some use if you get stuck.

Comment: @StochastikerUBERL Please [register your account](http://stats.stackexchange.com/users/login). This way you won't lose control of your posts any more.

Comment: mh, well thanks for trying to help me but I did not get it. So I don't know how to do it and I hope this will not come up tomorrow in the exam. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @Stoch: Did you read my comment carefully?

Comment: @cardinal A student's question: E(S_n^{-1}) looks like a Mellin transform with exponential $(n\alpha-1)-1$. So the term $n\alpha-1$ will go into a gamma function... doesn't this create a restriction on the value of $\alpha$ (or in the minimum sample size), so that $n\alpha-1\geq 0$?